# Android doesn't automatically save view states

Tags: android, android-savedstate

Basically, I have a `TextView` and two `EditText` views in one activity. From that activity, a different activity is started. If I press the hardware back button on the device (ending the second activity), the views' states are the same as before, which is good. However, after pressing the back button on the action bar (of the second activity), the views lose their previous state.

According to the docs, if you provide an ID for your views (widgets such as EditText, TextView, etc), android will automatically save their state.

> For example, the EditText widget saves any text entered by the user and the CheckBox widget saves whether it's checked or not. The only work required of you is to provide a unique ID (with the android:id attribute) for each widget you want to save its state. If a widget does not have an ID, then the system cannot save its state.

I have a unique id for each view that needs its state saved. I've also tried explicitly using `android:saveEnabled="true"` in XML and `textView.setSaveEnabled(true);` to no avail.

I've tried implementing `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` and calling `super` first thing for both. `onSaveInstanceState` is called as expected, but `onRestoreInstanceState` is never called. Also, `savedInstanceState` passed to `onCreate` is always `null`.

In the manifest, I've tried `android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"` and `android:stateNotNeeded="false"` with no luck.

I can post code, but I'm not sure what code would be relevant since the system doesn't seem to be doing what it's supposed to. What possible thing could cause the views' states to not be auto-saved by android? Any help is appreciated and I can post specific code if needed.

Sidenote: I'm using AppCompat if it makes any difference.

Comment: What is the state you are expecting to be saved? The text of a `TextView` won't be saved automatically, for example.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569790/android-onsaveinstancestate-in-back-button

Comment: @RicardoLage `For example, the EditText widget saves any text entered by the user` to quote the docs. The EditText in my case isn't saving its state automatically and I'm unable to even save it manually using `onSaveInstanceState` and such.

Comment: @user3529796 I meant the `TextView`, not the `EditText`. You didn't mention in your question where was the problem.

Comment: It was both that weren't saving. The answer works and now both are auto saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/activity_title"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:parentActivityName=".MyActivityParent">
    </activity>
```

Note the `android:launchMode="singleTop"` attribute.

By default, when the user presses the Back button, a new `Intent` is created, and your Activity is recreated from scratch. Setting the `launchMode` attribute in this way tells the ART to preserve and reuse the instance of your Activity.

Comment: I've run into this myself. Glad it helped!